# What are all the different "version" input field in MonoDevelop when using MonoTouch? How to auto increase version?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

In MonoDevelop I can see three places where I can edit versions for my app.

- First one is under *Project -> Solution Options:*
- Second one is *Project -> TestProject options (Main Settings)*
- Third one is *Project -> TestProject options (iPhone application)*

The second one I can opt to inherit from the parent. The third one is independent again.

What is the version that is going to be used when I submit to the App Store? Do I have to maintain all three versions?

Is there an option in MonoDevelop to automatically change the version with every build so that I don't have to do that manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important version in the third one - this is the info.plist file, which is important for the App Store.

As far as I know there is no way to increment the version automatically but you could try to do this via build script or add a feature request to the MonoTouch BugTracker

Comment: If I specify the 2nd one only, NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary.ValueForKey ( new NSString ("CFBundleVersion") ).ToString (); delivers "1.0" and not what I set.

Comment: Oh - you wrote the THIRD one. Why did I read 2nd? Damn. You're right! :-)

Answer (score 3):

> - First one is under Project -> Solution Options:
> - Second one is Project -> TestProject options (Main Settings)

I believe these are quite useless, nobody (but you) will actually see them.

> - Third one is Project -> TestProject options (iPhone application)

This is the important one, the one that clients will see in the App Store and when they've installed the app.

There is no built-in way to auto-increment it, but it's not hard to add a post-build script in MonoDevelop that does this for you (all you have to do is to modify the CFBundleVersion in Info.plist).

To read the version from the app bundle at runtime, do this:

```cs
NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary.ValueForKey (new NSString ("CFBundleVersion"));
```